# AForge.NET ffmpeg codec open error on Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, video, ffmpeg

I often get the below ffmpeg codec open error while I run the WPF application that I create using AForge.NET. I need to save videos from a few USB cameras simultaneously through multiple threads. I get the error after I record videos several times. If anyone had solved a similar issue and gave me some ideas to solve, I would appreciate it.

### Stack Trace

AForge.Video.VideoException - Cannot open video codec.
   at AForge.Video.FFMPEG.?A0xfb175571.open_video(WriterPrivateData data) in c:\projects\aforge.net\sources\video.ffmpeg\videofilewriter.cpp:line 459
   at AForge.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter.Open(String fileName, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 frameRate, VideoCodec codec, Int32 bitRate) in c:\projects\aforge.net\sources\video.ffmpeg\videofilewriter.cpp:line 159

### My environment

- Machine: Window 10 64bit
- Build Machine: Windows 8.1 64bit
- IDE: Visual Studio 2012
- Language: C#
- .NET version: 4.6.2
- ffmpeg version: AForge.NET Framework 2.2.5 (ffmpeg LGPL Ver.)
  https://aforgeffmpeg.codeplex.com/
- Codec: WMV2

Thanks in advance.